# Make middle item active in materialize carousel

Tags: css, carousel, materialize

I have a carousel built with materialize css. I want to start carousel from middle item. But carousel to be start from second item.
link of carousel: [link](https://chetorpedia.com)
What can I do?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please next time add a snippet of code to understand better...

Btw... You can use the `instance.set(x)` to move the carousel to nth slide (as stated in the docs [here](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html#methods))

Here is an example (just comment the `instance.set(middle_slide);` statement to see the difference):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //find wich slide is the middle one
  var carousel_items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item').length;
  var middle_slide = Math.round(carousel_items / 2) 
  
  console.log('The slide in the middle is the ' + middle_slide + ' out of ' + carousel_items)
  
  //Carousel initialization
  var options = {};
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
  var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  
  //Set the carousel to show the middle slide first
  var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
  var instance = M.Carousel.getInstance(elem);
  instance.set(middle_slide);
})
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen if you prefere: https://codepen.io/LukeSavefrogs/pen/WPYOGE?editors=1010